# Como fazer um INNER JOIN não repetir informações

Tags: php, inner

Tenho o seguinte **SQL INNER JOIN**:

```
$sqlxml = "
SELECT 
clientes.id, clientes.nome, clientes.status, clientes.cliente, clientes.tipo,
clientes.disponibilidade, imoveis.id, imoveis.cod, imoveis.status, imoveis.vanual, COUNT(imoveis.id) AS imoveis 
FROM clientes 
INNER JOIN imoveis ON clientes.cliente = imoveis.cod WHERE imoveis.status='2' AND clientes.status='2' AND imoveis.vanual < clientes.vanual AND imoveis.vanual <> '0' AND clientes.cliente = '$cliente' 
GROUP BY clientes.id";
```

Ele **repete** o imóvel duas vezes mesmo utilizando **GROUP BY**. Sendo que não há no Banco de dados esta informação repetida, o que faço?

Answer (score 1):

Quando a sua query usa uma função de agregação, você deve colocar *todos* os demais campos do SELECT em uma cláusula GROUP BY.

Sua query deveria ser

```
SELECT 
    clientes.id, clientes.nome, clientes.status, 
    clientes.cliente, clientes.tipo, clientes.disponibilidade, 
    imoveis.id, imoveis.cod, imoveis.status, imoveis.vanual, 
    COUNT(imoveis.id) AS imoveis 
FROM clientes 
    INNER JOIN imoveis 
        ON clientes.cliente = imoveis.cod 
WHERE 
    imoveis.status='2' 
    AND clientes.status='2' 
    AND imoveis.vanual < clientes.vanual 
    AND imoveis.vanual <> '0' 
    AND clientes.cliente = '$cliente' 
GROUP BY clientes.id, clientes.nome, clientes.status, 
    clientes.cliente, clientes.tipo, clientes.disponibilidade, 
    imoveis.id, imoveis.cod, imoveis.status, imoveis.vanual
```

Você não indicou se o seu servidor de banco de dados é o MySQL, mas se o servidor não acusou erro na sua query eu imagino que sim. O MySQL aceita "atalhos" no SQL que não são padrão, como omitir campos do GROUP BY ou a clausula por completo. Neste caso, acho que você pode conseguir o resultado que você quer usando apenas os campos da chave de clientes e imoveis.

```
GROUP BY clientes.id, imoveis.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve realizar o group by pelo campo "imoveis.id"
Ex:

```
$sqlxml = "
SELECT 
clientes.id, clientes.nome, clientes.status, clientes.cliente, clientes.tipo,
clientes.disponibilidade, imoveis.id, imoveis.cod, imoveis.status, imoveis.vanual, COUNT(imoveis.id) AS imoveis 
FROM clientes 
INNER JOIN imoveis ON clientes.cliente = imoveis.cod WHERE imoveis.status='2' AND clientes.status='2' AND imoveis.vanual < clientes.vanual AND imoveis.vanual <> '0' AND clientes.cliente = '$cliente' 
GROUP BY imoveis.id";
```